# Multiline selection of blocks with ID at the end of each block with regular expression

Tags: regex

I have regular expression:

```
BEGIN\s+\[([\s\S]*?)END\s+ID=(.*)\]
```

which select multiline text and ID from text below. I would like to select only IDs with prefix `X_`, but if I change `ID=(.*)` to `ID=(X_.*)` begin is selected from second pair not from third as I need. Could someone help me to get correct expression please?

text example:

```
BEGIN [
text a
END ID=X_1]

BEGIN [
text b
text c
END ID=Y_1]

text aaa
text bbb

BEGIN [
text d
text e
END ID=X_2]

text xxx

BEGIN [
text bbb
END ID=X_3]
```

Comment: Can we add a rule that there aren't any empty lines inside a `BEGIN[… END]` block? And using the character class `[\s\S]` is essentially `.`.

Comment: There can be anything between BEGIN[ .. END]. [\s\S] is used because . not include new line character.

Comment: What language is this?  The ones I know have a multi-line matching mode that allows `.` to match newlines.

Comment: @user1573190 There can't be any arbitrary data inside the block — the text `END ID=X_1]` is probably disallowed, but your rules don't recognize that. Is there an escaping mechanism or do we know anything more specific about the contents (like key-value pairs, only `\w` characters etc.)?

Comment: I have an application which convert file to format similar to example text and it uses regular expressions to extract ID and text. I have not control about anything except regular expression. In this application `[\s\S]` work for anything including new line character and `.` is interpreted as anything except new line character. Each block is begun with `BEGIN [` line and is ended with `END ID=..]` line. Between `BEGIN [ ... END ID=..]` are many lines wich can contains any text (e.g `text[1]` or `BEGIN` (without [). I need to select it from `BEGIN [` which is the nearest to the `END ID=X_]`.

Comment: @user1573190 What is "this application"? **What regex engine are you using?** It is very difficult (read: impossible) to come up with a real solution without knowing that! (Your file format is a broken design anyway.)

Comment: I know that this format is bad, ID after begin instead of after END tag would be much batter, but I get it as it is and unfortunately I can't change it. Regex engine is not mentioned in documentaction, there are only few examples of supported expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the `.*` that's gobbling everything up as people keep saying, it's the `[\s\S]*?`.  `.*` can't do it because (as the OP said) the dot doesn't match newlines.

When the `END\s+ID=(X_.*)\]` part of your regex fails to match the last line of the second block, you're expecting it to abandon that block and start over with the third one.  That's what it have to do to make the shortest match.

In reality, it backtracks to the beginning of the line and lets `[\s\S]*?` consume it instead.  And it keeps on consuming until it finds a place where `END\s+ID=(X_.*)\]` can match, which happens to be the last line of the third block.

The following regex avoids that problem by matching line by line, checking each one to see if it starts with `END`.  This effectively confines the match to one block at a time.

```
(?m)^BEGIN\s+\[[\r\n]+((?:(?!END).*[\r\n]+)*)END\s+ID=(X_.*)\]
```

Note that I used `^` to anchor each match to the beginning of a line, so I used `(?m)` to turn on multiline mode. But I did not--and you *should* not--turn on single-line/DOTALL mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming there aren't any newlines inside a block** and the `BEGIN`/`END` statements are the first non-space of their line, I'd write the regex like this (Perl notation; change the delimiters and remove comments, whitespaces and the `/x` modifier if you use a different engine)

```
m{
  \n \s* BEGIN \s+ \[          # match the beginning
     ( (?!\n\s*\n) .)*?        # match anything that isn't an empty line
                               # checking with a negative look-ahead (?!PATTERN)
  \n \s* END \s+ ID=X_[^\]]* \] # the ID may not contain "]"
}sx                            # /x: use extended syntax, /s: "." matches newlines
```

**If the content may be anything**, it might be best to create a list of all blocks, and then grep through them. This regex matches any block:

```
m{ (
  BEGIN \s+ \[
  .*?              # non-greedy matching is important here
  END \s+ ID=[^\]]* \] # greedy matching is safe here
) }xs
```

(add newlines if wanted)

Then only keep those matches that match this regex:

```
/ID = X_[^\]]* \] $/x  # anchor at end of line
```

If we don't do this, **backtracking may prevent a correct match** (`[\s\S]*?` can contain `END ID=X_`). Your regex would put anything inside the blocks until it sees a  `X_.*`.

So using `BEGIN\s+\[([/s/S]*?)END\s+ID=(.*?)\]` — note the extra question mark — one match would be:

```
BEGIN [
text b
text c
END ID=Y_1]

text aaa
text bbb

BEGIN [
text d
text e
END ID=X_2]
```

…instead of failing at the `Y_`. A greedy match (your unchanged regex) should result in the whole file being matched: Your `(.*)` eats up all characters (until the end of file) and then goes back until it finds a `]`.

#### EDIT:

Should you be using perls regex engine, we can use the `(*FAIL)` verb:

```
/BEGIN\s+\[(.*?)END\s+ID=(X_[^\]]*|(*FAIL))\]/s
```

"Either have an ID starting with `X_` or the match fails". However, this does not solve the problem with `END ID=X_1]`-like statements inside your data.

Comment: I can't use list of blocks because expression is input to application and post processing with grep is not possible.

Comment: @user1573190 Well, that depends. What Operating System are you targeting? What regex engine are you using? There is a workaround for every problem. Can't you just write a small script to do the conversion?

Comment: Application has own coverter which converts input files to text file similar to example text and from this file are selected IDs and their content with regular expression (conversion and parsing is done in one step). Output is shown in GUI and linked with IDs from another sources. Unfortunately I have only chance to use expression which matches the latest `BEGIN [` line before `END ID=..]`, but I am new in using of regexp and I am not sure if it is possible. In documentation are only few examples, specific engine is not mentioned. It is compiled and using under both unix and windows.

Comment: Supported is looking ahead/behind `(?=)` `(?!)` `(?<=)` `(?<!)`, . is interpreted as except new line character `[\s\S]` is anything including new line, `+?`, `*?` `(?:)` `[^\]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.*` to a `[^\]]*` (i.e. match non-]s), so that your matches can't spill over past an END block, giving you something like `BEGIN\s+\[([^\]]*?)END\s+ID=(X_[^\]]*)\]`

Comment: This works with example text, but my biggest problem is that text can contains any character including brackets. Only line with "BEGIN [" cannot be between BEGIN [ ... END ID=X_..].